# match atleast one element of given array of data in RethinkDB

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a data set like follows-

```
[{
    "name": "new name",
    "tags":[{
      "addedBy":  "userABCe3" ,
      "addedDTS": Tue Jan 23 2018 13:02:37 GMT+00:00 ,
      "tagId":  "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb821"
      },{
     "addedBy":  "userABCe3" ,
     "addedDTS": Tue Jan 23 2018 13:02:37 GMT+00:00 ,
     "tagId":  "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb823"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "data 1",
    "tags":[{
     "addedBy":  "userABCe3" ,
     "addedDTS": Tue Jan 23 2018 13:02:37 GMT+00:00 ,
     "tagId":  "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb823"
     },{
     "addedBy":  "userABCe3" ,
     "addedDTS": Tue Jan 23 2018 13:02:37 GMT+00:00 ,
     "tagId":  "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb824"
     }]
}]
```

i need to query, the data having any atleast one match in given tagIds array

```
[ "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb824", "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb822"]
```

expected **result** as follows :

```
[{
    "name": "data 1",
    "tags":[{
     "addedBy":  "userABCe3" ,
     "addedDTS": Tue Jan 23 2018 13:02:37 GMT+00:00 ,
     "tagId":  "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb823"
     },{
     "addedBy":  "userABCe3" ,
     "addedDTS": Tue Jan 23 2018 13:02:37 GMT+00:00 ,
     "tagId":  "08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb824"
     }]
}]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query worked for me

```
r.db('dbName').table("tableName").filter(function(doc){
    var tags = doc('tags')('tagId');
    var tagIds = ['08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb881','08d679c8-31b6-48d3-b8f3-3ab89f7bb823' ];
    var query = tagIds.map(function(tagId){
      return tags.contains(tagId)
    });
    return r.expr(query).contains(true)
  })
```